# Import all packages in main.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to import all my packages in only one file.

Let assume that I have a main.py file where I call all my class (from others .py files located in a src folder):

```
main.py
|-- src
  |-- package1.py
  |-- package2.py
```

the main.py looks like this:

```
from src.package1 import *
from src.package2 import *

def main():
    class1 = ClassFromPackage1()
    class2 = ClassFromPackage2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

in package1.py I import let say numpy, scipy and pandas

```
import numpy
import scipy
import pandas

class ClassFromPackage1():
    #  Do stuff using numpy, scipy and pandas
```

and in package2.py I use numpy and scikit learn:

```
import numpy
import sklearn

class ClassFromPackage2():
    #  Do stuff using numpy and sklearn
```

Is there a way to import all packages in one file Foo.py where I only write:

```
import numpy
import sklearn
import scipy
import pandas
```

and import this Foo.py in src .py? like this for example with package1.py

```
import Foo

class ClassFromPackage1():
    #  Do stuff using numpy, scipy and pandas
```

Is this a good idea? Does it reduce memory consumption? Will it helps python to start the main.py faster?

Comment: Good question. No, it will not run faster, and no, I don't think it is very useful. It is certainly not standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have already done it is how it is usually done. Similar to header files in C/C++, you make the dependencies explicit. And that it is a good thing.

You asked if it will run faster, the answer is no. All imports are shared. This, sometimes, causes unwanted side effects, but that is not the question here.

Comment: Thanks tobias, I made this example really 'clear' but in real life I import tensorflow and sklearn in multiple .py files and the main.py takes a lot of time to start (maybe ~2 secondes) because of this. 

I thought that all .py files import their own tf and sklearn packages. You confirm that I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. They are only loaded into memory once. It's the same as if you "import X" twice in the REPL. The first time it (might) take a second or two. The next time it will be immediate.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to make code cleaner? What you can do is create a file like `foo.py` and put all imports in it. Then you can import modules inside `foo.py` by doing

```py
from foo import *
```

This will indirectly import all modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I understand that I can do this but I don't know if it's a good idea in terms of practicality and speed (if it doesn't change anything.. I'm not sure it's usefull)

Comment: I guess it won't affect speed of the code and it is good ( you are basically just indirectly importing modules ). Also, that seems to be the only solution for this to me